# What is the Package Name when Unistalling an Application and Google Play

Tags: android, root

What is the Package Name/Broadcast Launched (if there is one) when the First Popup 'Do you really want to uninstall ...' appear, it is `com.android.setting` or something else?
And does Google Play/Old Market Version have different package names?

Comment: what exactly is your use case? are you looking for an intent to uninstall applications?

Comment: No , i have a service running in background wich check the top activity , and check package name eg. : "com.android.setting" iam looking for another package name (Unistall and Google Play)